# Union types / extension interfaces

Tags: oop, interface, kotlin

I have several `data class` with fields, which are used in forms and need  them to have a method return `true` if any of the fields has been filled.

I don't want to rewrite this for all the classes, so I'm doing it like this at the moment:

```
data class Order(var consumer: String, var pdfs: List<URI>): Form  {

    override val isEmpty(): Boolean
         get() = checkEmpty(consumer, pdfs)
}

data class SomethingElse(var str: String, var set: Set<String>): Form  {

    override val isEmpty(): Boolean
         get() = checkEmpty(str, set)
}


interface Form {
    val isEmpty: Boolean

    fun <T> checkEmpty(vararg fields: T): Boolean {
        for (f in fields) {
            when (f) {
                is Collection<*> -> if (!f.isEmpty()) return false
                is CharSequence -> if (!f.isBlank()) return false
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is obviously not very pretty nor type-safe.

What's a more idiomatic way of doing this, without abstracting every property into some kind of `Field`-type?

**Clarification:** What I'm looking for is a way to get exhaustive `when`, for example by providing all the allowed types (`String`, `Int`, `List`, `Set`) and a function for each to tell if they're empty. Like an "extension-interface" with a method `isEmptyFormField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are doing is checking for `isEmpty`/`isBlank`/`isZero`/etc. then you probably don't need a generic `checkEmpty` function, etc.:

```
data class Order(var consumer: String, var pdfs: List<URI>) : Form {
    override val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = consumer.isEmpty() && pdfs.isEmpty()
}

data class SomethingElse(var str: String, var set: Set<String>) : Form {
    override val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = str.isEmpty() && set.isEmpty()
}

interface Form {
    val isEmpty: Boolean
}
```

However, if you are actually do something a bit more complex then based on your added clarification I believe that "abstracting every property into some kind of `Field`-type" is exactly what you want just don't make the `Field` instances part of each `data class` but instead create a list of them when needed:

```
data class Order(var consumer: String, var pdfs: List<URI>) : Form {
    override val fields: List<Field<*>>
        get() = listOf(consumer.toField(), pdfs.toField())
}

data class SomethingElse(var str: String, var set: Set<String>) : Form {
    override val fields: List<Field<*>>
        get() = listOf(str.toField(), set.toField())
}

interface Form {
    val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = fields.all(Field<*>::isEmpty)

    val fields: List<Field<*>>
}

fun String.toField(): Field<String> = StringField(this)
fun <C : Collection<*>> C.toField(): Field<C> = CollectionField(this)

interface Field<out T> {
    val value: T
    val isEmpty: Boolean
}

data class StringField(override val value: String) : Field<String> {
    override val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = value.isEmpty()
}

data class CollectionField<out C : Collection<*>>(override val value: C) : Field<C> {
    override val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = value.isEmpty()
}
```

This gives you type-safety without changing your `data class` components, etc. and allows you to "get exhaustive `when`".

Comment: Still not entirely satisfied, cause it's very verbose, but I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's kinda hacky but should work.
Every `data class` creates set of method per each constructor parameters. They're called `componentN()` (where `N` is number starting from `1` indicating constructor parameter).

You can put such methods in your interface and make `data class` implicitly implement them. See example below:

```
data class Order(var consumer: String, var pdfs: List) : Form

data class SomethingElse(var str: String, var set: Set) : Form

interface Form {
    val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = checkEmpty(component1(), component2())

    fun  checkEmpty(vararg fields: T): Boolean {
        for (f in fields) {
            when (f) {
                is Collection -> if (!f.isEmpty()) return false
                is CharSequence -> if (!f.isBlank()) return false
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    fun component1(): Any? = null
    fun component2(): Any? = null
}
```

You can also add `fun component3(): Any? = null` etc... to handle cases with more that 2 fields in `data class` (e.g. `NullObject` pattern or handling `null`s directly in your `checkEmpty()` method.

As I said, it's kinda hacky but maybe will work for you.

Comment: Nice idea. You could also use reflection to list the component functions instead of creating nullable componentN methods.

Comment: This is a good idea, but what I was looking for was a way to get exhaustive `when`. E.g. providing functions of how to tell if an arbitrary type is "empty". (`isBlank()` for Strings, `isEmpty()` for Collections and so on)…

Answer (score 1):

You can use `null` to mean "unspecified":

```
data class Order(var consumer: String?, var pdfs: List<URI>?) : Form {
    override val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = checkEmpty(consumer, pdfs)
}

data class SomethingElse(var str: String?, var set: Set<String>?) : Form {
    override val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = checkEmpty(str, set)
}

interface Form {
    val isEmpty: Boolean
    fun <T> checkEmpty(vararg fields: T): Boolean = fields.all { field -> field == null }
}
```

The idea here is the same as that of an `Optional<T>` in Java but without the extra object, etc.

You now have to worry about [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) but if your fields are meant to have a concept of absent/empty then this seems appropriate ([UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)).

Comment: That way I lose a lot of null-safety in my code that uses these classes. I'd have to remember to set `List`s to null when they're empty and so on…